# Error: Requiring module "node_modules/axios/index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Restricted in strict mode, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

Getting an error saying,

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/axios/index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Restricted in strict mode, js engine: hermes
```

I'm getting this error when importing `axios` and trying to send an API request inside my react native project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply installed a pre-alpha version of axios,

```
npm i axios@1.2.0-alpha.1
```

And this solved my problem.
The resource https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5231

Example code,

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get<any>('https://flagcdn.com/en/codes.json')
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));
}, []);
```